# uninstall MySQL only from LAMP install Ubuntu 15.5

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, lamp

I believe there is an error with my MySQL install -- which was auto installed while installing Ubuntu 15.5/LAMP. I would like to only uninstall MySQL and try again, however the usual

```
"sudo apt-get remove --purge mysql-server mysql-client mysql-common
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo apt-get autoclean"
```

does not remove it and shows instead an option to remove the entire lamp image. How can I remove/reinstall MySQL only?

Comment: You cannot remove the mysql server whilst having the LAMP meta package installed, since that requires the mysql server. The whole point of a package management system is to prevent such situations. you can replace the mysql server by another package, or you can remove the LAMP package and install the packages separately. But a side note: just removing and reinstalling the mysql server package won't solve any issue you have.

Comment: Can you recommend the best way to uninstall the LAMP package? In the past I've installed Apache, PHP and MySQL all separately so I suppose thats what I'd like to do now.

Comment: If those packages are have been installed separately, then they will not have a common requirement for mysql and won't get removed alongside that one. There must be some other reasons which you should find out. Or does that "in the past" refer to other systems, not the current situation?

Comment: As written before I doubt that reinstalling the mysql server will fix any potential issues you have. Anyways, if you want to do that, then just reinstall it: `sudo apt-get install --reinstall  ...`

Comment: On a prior machine, I went through and installed all three separately vs this method, which is giving me some riffraff

Comment: I think I'd like to uninstall the entire LAMP package but haven't found a great resource for it online so far, but have read recommendations against sudo apt-get uninstall as it will affect more than just those packages